# excessive "access denied" logs?

Tags: users

I've setup a Drupal site and had to turn off user registration because of the amount of bogus accounts being created. Now when I check the logs I see loads of access denied messages, usually for pages 
node/add
user/register
[image]

Is this normal for a drupal (possibly any) site, and something to be expected? 
It seems excessive to me, so I'd like to understand if this is a normal problem for websites, drupal or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common problem. A spam bot has crawled your site, realizes it's a Drupal site, and it going through its functions to spam content (e.g. user register & node posting). This isn't exclusive to Drupal; there many kinds spam bot software that target specifics CMSes and any other comment/content submission forms.

You should look into various Drupal [spam prevention modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A7266&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search) like [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha), [Botcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha), etc.

Comment: though not usually with node/add and user/login or register (because they're smarter than that), it can also happen with search engine bots if the link used to be available (when developing for example) - it gets indexed and then removed from the site, but the bot will still look for it, sometimes for years after

Comment: If this could be spam/search bot, can I setup a robots.txt to solve the issue? also I am already using CAPTCHA it didn't seem to work very well as I ended up with loads of accounts. I have now turned on Admin only account creation. I still use CAPTCHA for logon.

Comment: well I just answered my own comment, robots.txt allready has disallow for the locations in the reports log.

Comment: Correct. While search bots also can exhibit hammering behavior like this, it's almost always content pages (in its index), not user/register or node/add. As you mentioned, node/add is under robots.txt so it's very likely a spambot you're dealing with.